# Proof for: $x \in \overline{A} \iff (x_n)_n$ exists in $A$ with $x_n \to x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

Does anyone know the proof for this double implication including the properties of secquences and the topology of sets?

$x \in \overline{A} \iff (x_n)_n$ exists in $A$ with $x_n \to x$

The $\overline{A}$ is the closure of the set $A$.

Comment: It kind of depends on your starting definitions of closure and sequence convergence. For example, this is equivalent to showing that $A\cap N$ is nonempty, for any neighborhood containing $x$, which also requires some additional underlying topological assumptions.

Comment: As far as "general topology" goes, this is false.

Comment: If you define the closure as the smallest closed subset of $A$ and you assume $A$ is part of $\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Here you have a notion of distance since you are talking of $x_n\rightarrow x$.  Suppose you define a closed set as a set that contains its limit points, and the closure of $A$ is the union of $A$ with its limit points. Then you can prove your claim by using the definition of "limit point" and, when appropriate, defining $x_n = x$ for all $n$.

Comment: It might be helpful for @SaucyO'Path to elaborate on the comment that this is false for "general topology."  What can go wrong? Which direction fails?

Comment: @Michael Why? She's already said that the question is in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path : I do not know what your comment/s mean.  It sounds like you are not elaborating because of a question about $\mathbb{R}$, and/or for some other issue that I do not know but you feel is "obvious." Several people have commented and, as of yet, there are no counter-examples provided.  It is not clear to me how the existing responses shed light on the issue of what can go wrong.

Comment: Nevermind.  I have constructed my own counter-example (for $\mathbb{R}$) using descriptions in the William Elliot answer.

Answer (score 3):

Right side implies left side for all spaces.
Within a 1st countable space, left side implies right side.

For each point there is a nhood base of a countable descending
nest of open sets.  Systematically pick a point from each of
those nhood base sets to construct the needed sequence.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I chased down links in the wiki article for "1st countable space" to get a more general defintion of $x_n\rightarrow x$, from which I then constructed an example where left-hand-side does not imply right-hand-side in general (see my other answer).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the smallest closed set that contains $A$ is equal to the union of $A$ with its limit points.  So the closure of $A$, denoted $\overline{A}$, can be taken to be the union of $A$ with its limit points.

#### 1) If we are in a metric space:

If a distance metric $d(x,y)$ exists and the topology of open sets is defined by the $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ function, then $x_n\rightarrow x$ means precisely that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} d(x_n,x)=0$.  Also, for every limit point $x$ of $A$, there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points in $A$ that are distinct from $x$ and satisfy $x_n\rightarrow x$.

So in this case, you can prove your desired *if and only if* statement using the method of my first comment.

[Note that my first comment assumed that a statement such as "$x_n\rightarrow x$" implicitly assumes existence of a distance metric $d(\cdot)$. However, by chasing down links from the William Elliot answer, I find a more general definition of $x_n\rightarrow x$ that does not require a distance metric, see "topological spaces" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence ]

#### 2) What can go wrong otherwise:

Here is a counter-example to show what can go wrong if we have neither a metric space nor a "first countable space" as mentioned in the William Elliot answer.

Let $X= \mathbb{R}$ and let the topology be the *cocountable topology*, where open sets are those that are either empty or the complement is finite or countable (see link here): 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology

Now take $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \neq 0\}$.

Then $0$ is a limit point of $A$ since every open set that contains $0$ must contain an infinite number of other points, and hence contains points in $A$.  So $\overline{A} = X = \mathbb{R}$.

So $0 \in \overline{A}$. However, take any infinite sequence of points $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $x_n \in A$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.  We want to show that we cannot have $x_n\rightarrow 0$. Consider the open set $U= \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \notin \{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\}$.  Then $0 \in U$ but, by definition of $U$,  there are no points of the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $U$. So we do not have $x_n\rightarrow 0$.   $\Box$

This shows the left-hand-side does not always imply the right-hand-side.

Comment: [0,$\omega_1$] is a compact Hausdorff counter example.

Comment: @WilliamElliot : I don't get the example.  What is $\omega_1$?  Is $[0,\omega_1]$ intended to be the interval of reals between $0$ and some positive number $\omega_1$?

Comment: It is the first uncountable ordinal.